# Vertical spacing legend without changing key height

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data (class:data.frame)

```
      tval            V2
  0.15992376 -0.8343450463
  0.10649188 -0.1661683709
  0.50782252 -0.3090289856
  0.40839714  1.3591006969
  0.87263438 -0.1140296582
 -0.67082150  0.5563068416
  1.04550767 -0.0835169157
  1.55295583  0.9997731998
  1.91169754  0.3246076173
 -0.25082386  0.0638465365
 -0.56745556  0.9553410876
  0.19166267 -0.4120324771
  2.29615058 -1.9694192327
  1.40662861 -1.0248516180
  1.91100408 -0.4167153416
 -0.06249463 -0.1230196521
 -2.38623303 -0.2223423823
 -1.84545755 -0.1886771462
  2.25594931 -2.6459779048
  0.11613099  0.5586652937
```

and the following code:

sizez<-14

```
library(tidyverse)
data1 %>% 
gather(key, value) %>% 
ggplot(aes(value, color=key)) + 
stat_ecdf(size=0.8) + xlim(-4.5,4.5) + 
labs(x = "t(alpha)", y = "Probability", color="Legend") + 
scale_colour_discrete(labels = c("Actual","Simulation")) +   
theme(legend.title=element_text(size=sizez+1),                     
legend.text=element_text(size=sizez), 
axis.text=element_text(size=sizez-1),                                                     
axis.title=element_text(size=sizez))
```

which produces this plot:

[image: plot]

My problem is how I can change the vertical spacing between the legends without changing the legend.key.height? It is the white spacing between the two legends (grey boxes) I want to be larger.

I have seen this solution:

```
sizez<-14

library(tidyverse)
data1 %>% 
gather(key, value) %>% 
ggplot(aes(value, color=key)) + 
stat_ecdf(size=0.8) + xlim(-4.5,4.5) + 
labs(x = "t(alpha)", y = "Probability", color="Legend") + 
scale_colour_discrete(labels = c("Actual","Simulation")) + 
theme(legend.title=element_text(size=sizez+1),    
legend.text=element_text(size=sizez),
axis.text=element_text(size=sizez-1), axis.title=element_text(size=sizez)), 
legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"),
legend.key.height = unit(2, "cm"))
```

Which produces:

[image]

But I want to keep the grey boxes around the key line, so it does not function for me. Anyone having a solution?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this? I modified the `legend.key` as well. You could place the legend on top and not worry about the space anymore.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp, color = as.factor(gear))) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(size = 6),
        legend.key.height = unit(1, "cm"),
        legend.key.width = unit(1, "cm"))
```

[image]

Comment: the problem with this solution is that the headline/header (Legend) and key on labels will come across each another. Can I then move the headline up of the legend a little up?

Comment: @Mads I think you should just save it as a pdf, move elements wherever you want.